# Insert data into SQLite db using python in metatrader 5

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to insert data into the SQLite database using python in Metatrader 5. but gives me [this error](https://mega.nz/file/j48EhK5B#gIAVxEcHcqtk_pbTI3wWa0Io6HL_BDhFSjnbIaU_G8c).

This is the python code:

```
import sqlite3
import MetaTrader5 as mt5

conn = sqlite3.connect('trades.db')
c = conn.cursor()

with conn:
    c.execute("INSERT INTO TRADES VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (1, 'eurusd', 'buy', 'running'))

conn.close()
```

the database [looks like this](https://mega.nz/file/a1kyTAKR#0BO7OBqS3lh6fFFJDiw7QzgxLgbCjK-mXkNm96uPCEQ).

what is the problem?

Comment: Please no images of code.

Comment: it seems like I need at least 10 reputations to post images. please check links

Comment: Please put the code as text

Comment: ok, I add the python code

Comment: @Max, is the DB name `trades.db` or `trades.sqlite`?

Comment: DB name is trades.sqlite

Comment: @Max, but you are opening `trades.db` in python code. I think that is why you are getting error

Comment: @Max please add all text as text. Don't post screenshots (especially not on some random file hosting websites). SO allows you to format text as code, there is literally no reason to make screenshots. its more bothersome for you and for us

Answer (score 0):

The error is "OperationalError: No such table TRADES".

Your database doesn't have a `TRADES` table; you'd need to create one with something like

```
conn.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TRADES (...)")
```

where `...` is, of course, your desired schema (which we can't quite help with).